# Array to string using nested objects and ngCSV in AngularJS

Tags: arrays, angularjs, csv

I'm dealing with an array of objects looking like this:

```
recordlist.push(
    {
        date: '', 
        time: '', 
        comment: '',
        arrival: '',
    }
```

I'm filtering it and displaying it on the front end like this:

```
ng-repeat="record in filteredRecords = (recordlist | filter:dateFilter | filter: search )"
```

This **filteredRecords** is the variable I use in the ngCSV to create the file:

```
<button ng-csv="filteredRecords"></button>
```

I was using ngCSV and it was working like a charm. But then I changed the structure and started using a nested array, turning the object into this:

```
recordlist.push(
    {
        date: '', 
        time: '', 
        comments: [
            {message: '',
            commenttime: ''},
            {message: '',
            commenttime: ''},
            {message: '',
            commenttime: ''}
        ],
        arrival: '',
    }
```

As ngCSV is not equipped to deal with nested objects, I guess I have to manipulate the data before adding it to the CSV file.

My idea would be something like turning the comments array into a string, writing it into the CSV on export, and turning it into an array again on import.

Something like:

```
comments: 'message: test, commenttime:test / message: test2, commenttime: test2 / ...'
```

How could I approach this?

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question you wanted to reformat you array of objects within an array of objects so that each individual object within the secondary array is now its own key:value in the original object.

You can do that with .map

something like:

```
$scope.MappedData = $scope.data.map(function (obj) {
    var reformattedObj = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < obj.comments.length; i++) {
        reformattedObj['comment' + [i]] = obj.comments[i];
    }
    reformattedObj['date'] = obj.date;
    reformattedObj['time'] = obj.time;
    reformattedObj['arrival'] = obj.arrival;

    return reformattedObj;
});
```

JS Fiddle Here: http://jsfiddle.net/chrislewispac/upny1107/